# Count how many of the same element in json

Tags: php, json

Im parsing json with php in this simple piece of code

```
    <?php
    $json = file_get_contents('list.json'); 
    $data = json_decode($json,true);
    $records=$data['records'];
    foreach($records as $record)
    {
       echo $record['number']." ".$record['opened_at'];
    }
    ?>
```

But i want to echo how many 'number' element are in my json file exemple bellow

```
{
"records":[
  {
     "number":"INC018****",
  },
  {
     "number":"INC018****",
  },
  {
     "number":"INC018****",
  },
  {
     "number":"INC018****",   
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('list.json'); 
$data = json_decode($json,true);
$records=$data['records'];
$numberCount = 0;
foreach($records as $record)
{
   $numberCount += isset($record['number']); // Here we go
   echo $record['number']." ".$record['opened_at'];
}
echo $numberCount;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This function might be helpful: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

```
$counts = array_count_values($records);
$numberCount = $counts['number'];
```